# Create a new column based on value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame:

```
 id|concept    |description
 12|           |rewards member
 12|tier one   |
 12|not avail  |rewards member
```

GOAL: Create a new column `final_desc` with the content in either the `concept` or `description` column

There are 4 possible scenarios:

1. There is a value in `concept` column and not in `description` , in which `final_desc` is the value in the  `concept`
2. There is a value in `description` column and not in `concept`, in which `final_desc` is the value in the  `description`
3. The value in `concept` column is *not avail* , in which `final_desc` is the value in the  `description`
4. Both the `concept` and `description` column are empty, in which `final_desc` is empty

I tried using a where statement but that does not account for scenario 3.

```
df['final_desc'] = np.where(df['concept'].isnull(), df['description'], df['concept'])
```

I think I need a custom function but am not sure how to write to work across columns

Answer (score 1):

You can combine a `replace` and `ffill/bfill`:

```
df['final_desc'] = (df[['concept','description']].replace('not avail',np.nan)
                     .bfill(1)['concept']
                   )
```

Output:

```
   id    concept     description      final_desc
0  12        NaN  rewards member  rewards member
1  12   tier one             NaN        tier one
2  12  not avail  rewards member  rewards member
```

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick:

```
df['final_desc'] = df.concept.replace('not avail',np.nan).fillna(df.description).fillna(df.concept.replace('not avail',np.nan))
```